# Is there a fastest way to write recordset results in an Excel table?

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I'm quite new to Stack Overflow and VBA, so forgive me.

```
For x = 1 To Rows
    For y = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
        Select Case rs.Fields(y - 1)
            Case rs![begin_date], rs![end_date]
                Z = CDate(rs.Fields(y - 1))
            Case rs![deadline_date]
                If rs![update_date] = "" Or IsNull(rs![update_date]) Then
                    Z = Calculate_deadline(rs![begin_date], rs![sla], _
                        rs![special_calendar])
                Else
                    Z = Calculate_deadline(rs![update_date], rs![sla], _
                        rs![special_calendar])
                End If
            Case Else
                Z = rs.Fields(y - 1)
        End Select
        table_list_object.HeaderRowRange.Cells(x + 1, y).Value = Z
    Next y
    rs.MoveNext
Next x
```

So, in a nutshell, I'm writing a VBA code in Access that executes a Query to gather  the data about all the project dates, calculates its deadlines and write all that in an Excel table.

The function part calculates the deadline date.

The problem is, I write every data one by one, like this:

```
table_list_object.HeaderRowRange.Cells(x + 1, y).Value = z
```

That might take a while, and I'm pretty sure this does slow down a lot my macro, but every VBA tutorial I saw did like this.

And I'm a little skeptical about the `Select Case` thing... Is it better that way, or should I use `If ... Else` instead?

Anyways, this Recordset has 15.000 rows but it's taking hours to execute, and the first times I ran this code it took some minutes, only.

Oh, by the way, the `Calculate_deadline` also might be the problem, I know. But I wanna be sure about this part of my code first, just to not make this question too big and complex to explain.

Thanks!

Comment: `Range.CopyFromRecordset`?

Comment: Will probably run faster if you can move the Calculate_deadline into your SQL and then you can use CopyFromRecordset as @MathieuGuindon suggests

Comment: To expand on @MathieuGuindon suggestion. Outside of your loop you can drop the entire recordset in one go: `table_list_object.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1,1).CopyFromRecordset rs`.  Highly highly agree though here that the loop should go away and be replaced with logic in your SQL that generates the recordset.

Comment: Do note: you can use user-defined VBA functions in Access SQL queries (but only through Access.exe GUI and not via ODBC/OLEDB).

Comment: @JNevill, Oooh. now I see the problem. Now my query take a little longer to run, but my code runs waaay faster now! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vitor, since you are new to VBA, I'd suggest that you consider another way to do this in Excel. Excel has a "Get Data" function that uses a technology called Power Query to pull data into Excel, manipulate it, and then save the manipulated data into a sheet in your Excel workbook. All of this using a point-and-click interface, rather than writing low-level VBA code.

See the following as an example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vchsUEHXvZo

This function is fairly easy to learn, and has common data manipulation functions, like filtering data, aggregating data, adding new calculated columns, transposing data, etc.

Just google "Power Query", and surf the videos and other resources out there.

Comment: I'm actually trying to avoid those interfaces, since I'm trying to code and learn VBA, so I guess this is not the best ideia for now, even if it's useful... But thank you for your reply, I'm definitely going to check this! (PS: I ended up using Range.CopyFromRecordset and put the function inside the query and it worked out great!)